# Extract XPath and Run it in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, console, syntax-error

There is dropdown list in a webpage, when I try to test the xpath from google chrome console with the following code:

```
$x("//*[@id="searchResultsList"]/li[2]/div/div/div/pagination-component/div[1]/div[4]/span[2]/select/option[4]")
```

I see the following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

But I think my syntax is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, your strings are not correctly formatted.

```
$x("//*[@id='searchResultsList']/li[2]/div/div/div/pagination-component/div[1]/div[4]/span[2]/select/option[4]")
```